# Copy everything except when the value is the same

Tags: xslt, duplicates

I am very unexperienced so I'd like some help.

I exported a Filemaker database in XML, this is the result

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Questa grammatica non è più in uso - usare FMPXMLRESULT al suo posto -->
<FMPDSORESULT>
<ROW MODID="5" RECORDID="2">
    <FASCICOLO>Adams John</FASCICOLO>
    <TITOLO_DOC>John Adams to Mr X</TITOLO_DOC>
    <LUOGO>New York</LUOGO>
    <GG>27</GG>
    <MM>04</MM>
    <AA>1969</AA>
    <CONTENUTO>Greetings</CONTENUTO>
    <TIPOLOGIA>letter</TIPOLOGIA>
    <NUM_CARTE>1</NUM_CARTE>
    <INTEGR_DESC/>
</ROW>
<ROW MODID="6" RECORDID="6">
    <FASCICOLO>Adams John</FASCICOLO>
    <TITOLO_DOC>John Adams to Mr X</TITOLO_DOC>
    <LUOGO>s.l.</LUOGO>
    <GG>03</GG>
    <MM>07</MM>
    <AA>1996</AA>
    <CONTENUTO>Greetings</CONTENUTO>
    <TIPOLOGIA>letter</TIPOLOGIA>
    <NUM_CARTE>3</NUM_CARTE>
    <INTEGR_DESC>Presente la busta originale.</INTEGR_DESC>
</ROW>
```

etc. (I haven't copied it all)

I used this XSL file to transform it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="iso-8859-1"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:element name="dsc">
        <xsl:for-each select="//ROW">
            <xsl:element name="c">
                <xsl:attribute name="level">file</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="id">.</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:element name="did">
                    <xsl:element name="unittitle">
                        <xsl:attribute name="encodinganalog">ISAD 1 - 2 title</xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:value-of select="./FASCICOLO/text()"/>
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

and I got this XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<dsc>
<c level="file" id=".">
    <did>
        <unittitle encodinganalog="ISAD 1 - 2 title">Adams John</unittitle>
    </did>
</c>
<c level="file" id=".">
    <did>
        <unittitle encodinganalog="ISAD 1 - 2 title">Adams John</unittitle>
    </did>
</c>
<c level="file" id=".">
    <did>
        <unittitle encodinganalog="ISAD 1 - 2 title">Doe Jane</unittitle>
    </did>
</c>
<c level="file" id=".">
    <did>
        <unittitle encodinganalog="ISAD 1 - 2 title">Doe Jane</unittitle>
    </did>
</c>
<c level="file" id=".">
    <did>
        <unittitle encodinganalog="ISAD 1 - 2 title">Doe Jane</unittitle>
    </did>
</c>
<c level="file" id=".">
    <did>
        <unittitle encodinganalog="ISAD 1 - 2 title">Doe Jane</unittitle>
    </did>
</c>
<c level="file" id=".">
    <did>
        <unittitle encodinganalog="ISAD 1 - 2 title">Green Charles</unittitle>
    </did>
</c>
<c level="file" id=".">
    <did>
        <unittitle encodinganalog="ISAD 1 - 2 title">Green Charles</unittitle>
    </did>
</c>
<c level="file" id=".">
    <did>
        <unittitle encodinganalog="ISAD 1 - 2 title">Green Charles</unittitle>
    </did>
</c>
<c level="file" id=".">
    <did>
        <unittitle encodinganalog="ISAD 1 - 2 title">Jones Charles</unittitle>
    </did>
</c>
<c level="file" id=".">
    <did>
        <unittitle encodinganalog="ISAD 1 - 2 title">White Walter</unittitle>
    </did>
</c>
```

I need to get the same, but with the names repeated only once, this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<dsc>
<c level="file" id=".">
    <did>
        <unittitle encodinganalog="ISAD 1 - 2 title">Adams John</unittitle>
    </did>
</c>
<c level="file" id=".">
    <did>
        <unittitle encodinganalog="ISAD 1 - 2 title">Doe Jane</unittitle>
    </did>
</c>
<c level="file" id=".">
    <did>
        <unittitle encodinganalog="ISAD 1 - 2 title">Green Charles</unittitle>
    </did>
</c>
<c level="file" id=".">
    <did>
        <unittitle encodinganalog="ISAD 1 - 2 title">Jones Charles</unittitle>
    </did>
</c>
<c level="file" id=".">
    <did>
        <unittitle encodinganalog="ISAD 1 - 2 title">White Walter</unittitle>
    </did>
</c>
```

This is an example, the real file will be much bigger with possibly a lot of duplicates, so I don't want to delete them manually. Is it possible? Thank you very much

Comment: Your question is very vague and you failed to mention how you intend to do any of this. Will you be using .NET, PHP, Python, other?

Comment: Sorry
I meant to use XSL, but as you can see I know very little of these things

Comment: Have you tried any XSLT so far? If so, please let us know your starting point.

Comment: I edited the first post trying to explain myself better

Answer (score 1):

First, if you are exporting from Filemaker, you can eliminate duplicates in the result at the source.

Secondly, if you are applying the XSLT during the export, you can use the `xalan:distinct()` extension function to eliminate the duplicates during the transformation. If you are using version 11 or higher, the EXSLT `set:distinct()` function is also available.